# Column reorder at runtinme

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using the [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) plugin for jQuery and I would like to reorder the columns after the data is loaded. I know I can reorder them upon creating the table.

What I would like to do is to draw the table, load the data from the server and then, based on the response from the server, to reorder the columns.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do so by using the DataTables plugin `ColReorder`. After enabling the plugin the columns can be moved with the `fnColReorder(from, to)` like this:

```
var table = jQuery("#table_id").dataTable(settings);
table.fnColReorder(4, 10);//move the 4th column on the 10th position
table.fnAdjustColumnSizing();//a good idea to make sure there will be no displaying issues
```

But there should be payed some attention when using the column indexes: these are the indexes from within the table's columns array. These means, that the index does not have to match the column's number in the table(some columns can be hidden, according to your specification).